# Создание компонента react, отображение в storybook с помощью knobs

Tags: reactjs

Создаю компонент в сторибуке, он состоит из заголовка (h1) и описания (p), соответственно с разными стилями. Компонент будет переиспользоваться и нужно сделать абстрактные привязки, чтобы при открытие в сторибуке можно было менять текст, как у заголовка так и у описания. У меня получается сделать только заголовок, если я хочу прикрутить ещё и абзац с описанием то перестаёт работать. Ниже код с попыткой привязки абзаца.

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Text.module.css';

interface ITextProps {
    title: string;
    description: string;
}

const Text: React.FC<ITextProps> = ({ title, description }) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className={styles.title}>
                {title}
            </h1>
            <p className={styles.description}>
                {description}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Text;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { withKnobs, text } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';
import Text from '../components/Text/Text';

export default {
    title: 'Text',
    component: Text,
    decorators: [withKnobs]
};

export const Текст = () => (
    <Text title="Title" description="Description">
        {text('Title', 'Заголовок')}
        {text('Title', 'Описание')}
    </Text>
);
```

Comment: можете на codesandbox загрузить?

Comment: Не получается корректно залить, много всего